# Fail to "compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac" - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio

I have looked for awhile on Internet and inside the forum, but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

When I compile an run the app, everything is okey. The app is installed on my phone, everything works. But when I try to run one unit test android studio shows me this :

[image: Build failed - Run tasks failed]

And here is the  error messages :

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:95)
```

So recently I had an issue with my laptop and I had to reboot from factory so I lost all my work on Android Studio. Before everything was okey, the unit tests worked. Now not anymore, and I am sure that I have written as it was before. (Took pictures of what I have done in order to copy after).

I have tried all the things I could find, but none of them worked. 
I have already tried to clean-rebuild project, download the Java JDK (but I can run the app, so it shouldn't be because of that I think), check if I have added the good libraries of Mockito/Powermockito in the unit tests, check if my dependencies in the gradle are okey. And now I am stuck.

If anyone can help me please. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you updated android studio to 3.1

Comment: Yes I did. My android studio is 3.1, the latest one

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution after awhile. As my project is a shared project, there are other unit tests that I didn't really care at the beginning. I have found that they had issues. And i don't know why, but when I run one specific unit test, it 'runs'/'do something with'  other unit tests located in other classes. But android studio didn't notify me that it ran them.

So I have fixed/commented them, and now it works well !